# Does making fun of the short beards of Muslims amount to kufr?

Tags: kufr, beard

I was in the mosque and I saw a man with a short beard. I felt the impulse to laugh because I think I found the style of his beard funny. I told myself not to laugh because it might constitute making fun of Islam. I don't think I laughed but I think my expression changed I think I acted upon the waswas I got. Have I committed kufr?

And even if I did laugh, is there a difference between laughing at the style of his beard and laughing at the act of keeping a beard for the sake of Allah?

Comment: What was your (intention -if there was any-) when you laughed or almost laughed? As you say it was the beard style made you laugh, where is the kufr here?

Comment: i did not laugh. I felt an impulse to do so. I dont think my intention was to laugh at the sunnah of keeping a beard as i keep a beard myself. I think it was the style of the beard

Comment: So kufr is out of question!

Comment: that is a relief

Comment: if you're online i'd like to talk to you about something

Comment: but if you aren't, could you tell me when i can get you online?

Comment: it's very important

Comment: ok. i need to talk to you about the issue of waswas

Comment: are you familiar with it?

Comment: i'll still give it a try.

Comment: I had these images of Allah back from when i was a child. I know that this is shirk. When i grew up i understood what this meant and tried to get rid of the images. Sometimes however, it doesn't work. I get these images and if i'm about to do a sin i get frightened thinking of Allah and i don't do the sin. I know that this is action upon the images which is clear blasphemy. I tried to repel these images but sometimes i'm caught unaware and i don't even know that i had these images until much later. Sometimes i'm aware but i still act upon it.What should i do?

Comment: if you're online i'd like to talk to you again. It seems they've deleted the chat room

Comment: how do i make a new one?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. It equates to fusuq (evil-doing).

> Narrated `Abdullah: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Abusing a Muslim is
> Fusuq (i.e., an evil-doing), and killing him is Kufr (disbelief).
>
> Reference: Sahih al-Bukhari 6044
>
> USC-MSA web (English) reference: Vol. 8, Book 73, Hadith 70

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I assume you are right and factually it is not Kuffr if ...